# $.getJson won't affect view until event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asynchronous

Didn't really know how to word the question. Using angular. Anyways, I'm trying to have it so when the user types in the text box a state, once it has been verified that the state exists (comparing to an array of all 50), it will automatically call a getJSon Jquery request for a JSON object. But for some reason, it doesn't execute right away, instead I have to press a key after doing so.

Code:

```
 $scope.checkState = function(team) {
    //check for team
    console.log("Searching for " + document.getElementById('team').value)

    var teamFind = document.getElementById('team').value;
    var team = $.inArray(teamFind, $scope.states);
    console.log("team: " + team);

    if (team == -1)
    {
       console.log("Not found");
       $scope.selectedState = "Not Found";
       teamFound = false;
    }
    //correct team
    if (team > -1)
    {
        $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ak21r', function (data) {
             //console.log(data.bowl);
             $scope.items = data;
             console.log($scope.items);
              console.log("Team Bowl:  " + team_bowl)
        console.log("Found: " + $scope.states[team]);
        $scope.selectedState = $scope.states[team];
        teamFound = true;
         });

    }

}
```

html code

```
  <p class="w3-large w3-center">
        <input type="text" name="team" id="team" value="Whats Your Team?"    ng-keyup="checkState(team)">
   </p>
   <p class="w3-jumbo w3-center">
    <span id="bowl">{{ selectedState }}</span>
</p>
<p class="w3-large w3-center">
<span>f{{ items }}</span>
</p>

</div>
```

I know it might be hard to understand what I want, but I was creating a sample application that would show what bowl game a team was competing in. The user types the team into the text-box id=team below, and I wanted it done without them having to press enter or submit.

On the key-up, it runs the check function. So for example, once Maryland is entered, the getJson will run and correctly logs the data, but the $scope.items isn't updated until after I type one more key AFTER I entered the state

So like typing:

M-A-R-Y-L-A-N-D(CONSOLE LOGS THE JSON OBJECT CORRECTLY, BUT ON THE HTML {{ items }} STILL SHOWS NOTHING)-*any_key_here*(NOW IT GETS UPDATED)

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

So I was able to get it by having another function be called with the data inside the JSON function.

```
 myFunction(data);
```

which calls

```
function myFunction(items) { 

 console.log(items);
 document.getElementById('bowl2').innerHTML = items.team;

};
```

Comment: Do **NOT** use jQuery's ajax directly with angular. For this case, angular provides [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) which can be injected. `$http` is very similar to jQuery's ajax (in fact, if jQuery is there, it will wrap/user jQuery, but do extra things which you are missing)

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery's ajax method which does not integrate with angular to inform angular when it is done. It's best to use angular's built in [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) methods which do the same thing expect when they complete they trigger a digest cycle which will update the view.

You will need to inject `$http` into your controller or service (depending on where this code lives) in order to use it. Once you do that, you should be able to make the following modification to you code.

Change

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ak21r', function (data) {
         //console.log(data.bowl);
         $scope.items = data;
         console.log($scope.items);
          console.log("Team Bowl:  " + team_bowl)
    console.log("Found: " + $scope.states[team]);
    $scope.selectedState = $scope.states[team];
    teamFound = true;
     });
```

to

```
$http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ak21r')
  .then(function (response) {
    var data = response.data;
    //console.log(data.bowl);
    $scope.items = data;
    console.log($scope.items);
    console.log("Team Bowl:  " + team_bowl)
    console.log("Found: " + $scope.states[team]);
    $scope.selectedState = $scope.states[team];
    teamFound = true;
  });
```